# Is telling the police "no" going to be my downfall?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In skimming through the Spectre terminal, I found a request for surveillance from C-Sec.

> "Spectre authorization would enable C-Sec to tap into business feeds
>   without informing civilian agencies."

This is something I would probably complain about in reality, so I am tempted to just leave it unauthorized. However, since this is a game, I wonder what negative or positive effects it may have.

Are there any downfalls to leaving this request unauthorized?

Comment: There's another, similar decision you can make at one point, with a Cafe owner who doesn't want to surrender his security tapes to a C-Sec officer.  FYI, you can support the Cafe owner and not lose war assets, from what I can tell.

Comment: You're right to question this decision, for while this one helps you slightly, there are at least 2 decisions you can authorize that hurt you, so always question whether it seems like a good idea or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorizing this makes a small War Asset change (+7) to the [Citadel Defense Force](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/War_Assets/Alien#Citadel_Defense_Force).  Not authorizing it appears to do nothing.

The asset will be updated with:

> A Spectre gave C-Sec permission to tap into surveillance on private citizens. C-Sec used the footage to make several arrests, improving security.

If authorizing it bothers you, I'd ignore it :)